Envoy is not terminating the TLS connection at listeners
envoy is not terminating the TLS connection at listeners instead it forwards to the services. Due to this, my service is failing as it only accepts the plain TCP connection.
I have envoy running as a sidecar in both my_service_1 and my_service_2 instances as below,
my_service_1(tcp on port 1062) --> my_service_1_envoy_sidecar(tls on port 2062) --> my_service_2_envoy_sidecar(tls on port 3062) --> my_service_2(tcp port 4062)
below config used for both services:
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: incoming_request_to_local_my_service
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: ENVOY_LOCAL_PORT #(2062 for service_1 and 3062 for service_2)
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.tcp_proxy
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.tcp_proxy.v3.TcpProxy
                stat_prefix: tcp_proxy
                cluster: local_my_service
                access_log:
                  - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
          transport_socket:
            name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
              common_tls_context:
                tls_certificates:
                  - certificate_chain: { "filename": "/config/cert/server-cert.pem" }
                    private_key: { "filename": "/config/cert/server-key.pem" }
    - name: outgoing_request_to_remote_my_service
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: LOCAL_MY_SERVICE_IP_ADDR #(current host ip address)
          port_value: OTHER_MY_SERVICE_ENVOY_PORT #(3062 for service_1 and 2062 for service_2)
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.tcp_proxy
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.tcp_proxy.v3.TcpProxy
                stat_prefix: tcp_proxy
                cluster: remote_my_service
                access_log:
                  - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
  clusters:
    - name: local_my_service
      type: static
      connect_timeout: 5s
      dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: local_my_service
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: LOCAL_SERVICE_IP_ADDR #(current host ip address)
                      port_value: MY_SERVICE_PORT #(1062 for service_1 and 4062 for service_2)
    - name: remote_my_service
      type: static
      connect_timeout: 5s
      dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: remote_my_service
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: REMOTE_SERVICE_IP_ADDR #(remote my_service host ip address)
                      port_value: REMOTE_ENVOY_PORT #(3062 for service_1 and 2062 for service_2)
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            validation_context:
              trusted_ca:
                filename: /config/cert/ca-cert.pem
admin:
  access_log_path: /var/log/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 127.0.0.1
      port_value: 9908

The request failed with errors:
[2024-06-11 11:05:59.520][994][debug][main] [external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:209] flushing stats
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.521][994][debug][main] [external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:209] flushing stats
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.781][1012][debug][filter] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:249] [C0] new tcp proxy session
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.781][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:349] [C0] readDisable: disable=true disable_count=0 state=0 buffer_length=0
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.782][1012][debug][filter] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:397] [C0] Creating connection to cluster local_my_service
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.785][1012][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:98] creating a new connection
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.786][1012][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:383] [C1] connecting
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.786][1012][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:860] [C1] connecting to 200.0.0.2:4062
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.786][1012][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:876] [C1] connection in progress
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.787][1012][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:125] queueing request due to no available connections
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.787][1012][debug][conn_handler] [external/envoy/source/server/active_tcp_listener.cc:328] [C0] new connection
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.787][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:547] [C0] socket event: 2
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.787][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:656] [C0] write ready
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.814][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_handshaker.cc:237] [C0] ssl error occurred while read: WANT_READ
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.814][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:547] [C1] socket event: 2
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.814][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:656] [C1] write ready
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.814][1012][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:665] [C1] connected
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.814][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:410] [C1] raising connection event 2
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.815][1012][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:303] [C1] assigning connection
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.815][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:349] [C0] readDisable: disable=false disable_count=1 state=0 buffer_length=0
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.815][1012][debug][filter] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:660] [C0] TCP:onUpstreamEvent(), requestedServerName: 
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.816][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:547] [C0] socket event: 2
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.816][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:656] [C0] write ready
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.816][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_handshaker.cc:237] [C0] ssl error occurred while read: WANT_READ
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.831][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:547] [C0] socket event: 3
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.831][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:656] [C0] write ready
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.838][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:410] [C0] raising connection event 2
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.839][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:585] [C0] read ready. dispatch_buffered_data=false
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.839][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:92] [C0] ssl read returns: -1
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.839][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:132] [C0] ssl error occurred while read: WANT_READ
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.839][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:168] [C0] ssl read 0 bytes
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.845][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:547] [C0] socket event: 3
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.845][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:656] [C0] write ready
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.845][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:585] [C0] read ready. dispatch_buffered_data=false
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.846][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:92] [C0] ssl read returns: 1161
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.846][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:92] [C0] ssl read returns: -1
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.846][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:132] [C0] ssl error occurred while read: WANT_READ
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.846][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:168] [C0] ssl read 1161 bytes
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.846][1012][trace][filter] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:570] [C0] downstream connection received 1161 bytes, end_stream=false
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.846][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:470] [C1] writing 1161 bytes, end_stream false
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.847][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:547] [C1] socket event: 2
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.847][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:656] [C1] write ready
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.847][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/raw_buffer_socket.cc:67] [C1] write returns: 1161
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.878][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:547] [C1] socket event: 3
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.878][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:656] [C1] write ready
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.878][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:585] [C1] read ready. dispatch_buffered_data=false
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.879][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/raw_buffer_socket.cc:24] [C1] read returns: 402
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.879][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/raw_buffer_socket.cc:38] [C1] read error: Resource temporarily unavailable
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.879][1012][trace][filter] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:616] [C0] upstream connection received 402 bytes, end_stream=false
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.879][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:470] [C0] writing 402 bytes, end_stream false
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.880][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:547] [C0] socket event: 2
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.880][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:656] [C0] write ready
[2024-06-11 11:06:04.880][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:254] [C0] ssl write returns: 402
[2024-06-11 11:06:05.304][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:547] [C1] socket event: 3
[2024-06-11 11:06:05.304][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:656] [C1] write ready
[2024-06-11 11:06:05.305][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:585] [C1] read ready. dispatch_buffered_data=false
[2024-06-11 11:06:05.305][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/raw_buffer_socket.cc:24] [C1] read returns: 603
[2024-06-11 11:06:05.305][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/raw_buffer_socket.cc:38] [C1] read error: Resource temporarily unavailable
[2024-06-11 11:06:05.305][1012][trace][filter] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:616] [C0] upstream connection received 603 bytes, end_stream=false
[2024-06-11 11:06:05.305][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:470] [C0] writing 603 bytes, end_stream false
[2024-06-11 11:06:05.305][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:547] [C0] socket event: 2
[2024-06-11 11:06:05.305][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:656] [C0] write ready
[2024-06-11 11:06:05.305][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:254] [C0] ssl write returns: 603
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.333][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:547] [C1] socket event: 3
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.333][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:656] [C1] write ready
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.333][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:585] [C1] read ready. dispatch_buffered_data=false
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.333][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/raw_buffer_socket.cc:24] [C1] read returns: 766
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.333][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/raw_buffer_socket.cc:38] [C1] read error: Resource temporarily unavailable
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.333][1012][trace][filter] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:616] [C0] upstream connection received 766 bytes, end_stream=false
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.333][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:470] [C0] writing 766 bytes, end_stream false
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.334][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:547] [C0] socket event: 2
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.334][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:656] [C0] write ready
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.334][1012][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:254] [C0] ssl write returns: 766
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.470][1022][debug][filter] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:249] [C2] new tcp proxy session
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.470][1022][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:349] [C2] readDisable: disable=true disable_count=0 state=0 buffer_length=0
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.470][1022][debug][filter] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:397] [C2] Creating connection to cluster local_my_service
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.470][1022][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:98] creating a new connection
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.470][1022][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:383] [C3] connecting
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.470][1022][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:860] [C3] connecting to 200.0.0.2:4062
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.470][1022][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:876] [C3] connection in progress
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.470][1022][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:125] queueing request due to no available connections
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.471][1022][debug][conn_handler] [external/envoy/source/server/active_tcp_listener.cc:328] [C2] new connection
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.471][1022][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:547] [C2] socket event: 2
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.471][1022][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:656] [C2] write ready
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.471][1022][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_handshaker.cc:237] [C2] ssl error occurred while read: SSL
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.472][1022][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:219] [C2] TLS error: 268435703:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.472][1022][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:243] [C2] closing socket: 0
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.473][1022][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:219] [C2] TLS error: 268435703:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.473][1022][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:410] [C2] raising connection event 0
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.473][1022][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:223] canceling pending request
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.473][1022][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:231] canceling pending connection
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.473][1022][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:133] [C3] closing data_to_write=0 type=1
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.473][1022][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:243] [C3] closing socket: 1
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.474][1022][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:410] [C3] raising connection event 1
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.474][1022][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:140] [C3] client disconnected
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.474][1022][trace][main] [external/envoy/source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:252] item added to deferred deletion list (size=1)
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.474][1022][debug][conn_handler] [external/envoy/source/server/active_tcp_listener.cc:76] [C2] adding to cleanup list
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.474][1022][trace][main] [external/envoy/source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:252] item added to deferred deletion list (size=2)
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.474][1022][trace][main] [external/envoy/source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:252] item added to deferred deletion list (size=3)
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.475][1022][trace][main] [external/envoy/source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:115] clearing deferred deletion list (size=3)
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.475][1022][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:255] [C3] connection destroyed
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.985][1022][debug][filter] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:249] [C4] new tcp proxy session
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.985][1022][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:349] [C4] readDisable: disable=true disable_count=0 state=0 buffer_length=0
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.985][1022][debug][filter] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:397] [C4] Creating connection to cluster local_my_service
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.986][1022][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:98] creating a new connection
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.986][1022][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:383] [C5] connecting
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.986][1022][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:860] [C5] connecting to 200.0.0.2:4062
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.986][1022][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:876] [C5] connection in progress
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.986][1022][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:125] queueing request due to no available connections
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.986][1022][debug][conn_handler] [external/envoy/source/server/active_tcp_listener.cc:328] [C4] new connection
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.986][1022][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:547] [C4] socket event: 2
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.986][1022][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:656] [C4] write ready
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.986][1022][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_handshaker.cc:237] [C4] ssl error occurred while read: SSL
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.986][1022][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:219] [C4] TLS error: 268435703:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.987][1022][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:243] [C4] closing socket: 0
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.987][1022][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:219] [C4] TLS error: 268435703:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.987][1022][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:410] [C4] raising connection event 0
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.987][1022][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:223] canceling pending request
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.987][1022][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:231] canceling pending connection
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.987][1022][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:133] [C5] closing data_to_write=0 type=1
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.987][1022][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:243] [C5] closing socket: 1
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.987][1022][trace][connection] [external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:410] [C5] raising connection event 1
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.987][1022][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:140] [C5] client disconnected
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.987][1022][trace][main] [external/envoy/source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:252] item added to deferred deletion list (size=1)
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.987][1022][debug][conn_handler] [external/envoy/source/server/active_tcp_listener.cc:76] [C4] adding to cleanup list
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.987][1022][trace][main] [external/envoy/source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:252] item added to deferred deletion list (size=2)
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.987][1022][trace][main] [external/envoy/source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:252] item added to deferred deletion list (size=3)
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.987][1022][trace][main] [external/envoy/source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:115] clearing deferred deletion list (size=3)
[2024-06-11 11:06:06.987][1022][debug][pool] [external/envoy/source/common/tcp/original_conn_pool.cc:255] [C5] connection destroyed
[2024-06-11 11:06:09.525][994][debug][main] [external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:209] flushing stats
[2024-06-11 11:06:14.531][994][debug][main] [external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:209] flushing stats
[2024-06-11 11:06:19.533][994][debug][main] [external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:209] flushing stats


